# flutter - How to Speed Up Compute for Parsing Json Function

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a function in `bloc` that needs to retrieve data from API then parse and load them into the widget.

For Data Retrieval from API, it's so fast. However, I see a **bottleneck** when parsing the json, as seen as below code :

```
      response = await dio.get("/article/get-random?category=1&lang=${translations.currentLanguage}");
      var data = response.data['data'];
      print(data);
      articleList.clear();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        //data length is 5
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

          //Start of The Bottleneck is here...

          model = await compute(articleFromJson, json.encode(data[i]));
          articleList.add(model);

          //End of The Bottleneck
        }

        print ("above code take around 5 seconds");

        // sink to the stream
        _articlesController.sink.add(articleList);
        _loadingArticleController.sink.add(false);
        await Storage.storeArticles(data);
      }
```

This Code : `model = await compute(articleFromJson, json.encode(data[i]));` **take around 3-5 seconds to complete**, sometime longer.

and here're the class where function code of `articleFromJson` reside :

```
import 'dart:convert';

Article articleFromJson(String str) {
    final jsonData = json.decode(str);
    return Article.fromJson(jsonData);
}

String articleToJson(Article data) {
    final dyn = data.toJson();
    return json.encode(dyn);
}

class Article {

    int id;
    int category;
    String name;
    String baseUrl;
    String url;
    String imageUrl;
    dynamic data;
    int status;
    int order;
    DateTime createdAt;
    DateTime updatedAt;
    String categoryLabel;

    Article({
        this.id,
        this.category,
        this.name,
        this.baseUrl,
        this.url,
        this.imageUrl,
        this.data,
        this.status,
        this.order,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
        this.categoryLabel,
    });

    factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Article(
        id: json["id"],
        category: json["category"],
        name: json["name"],
        baseUrl: json["base_url"],
        url: json["url"],
        imageUrl: json["image_url"],
        data: json["data"],
        status: json["status"],
        order: json["order"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
        categoryLabel: json["category_label"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "category": category,
        "name": name,
        "base_url": baseUrl,
        "url": url,
        "image_url": imageUrl,
        "data": data,
        "status": status,
        "order": order,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
        "category_label": categoryLabel,
    };
}
```

The Json Data itself so simple like below (only 5 rows) :

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 990121,
            "category": 1,
            "name": "Article 1 Title",
            "base_url": "base_url",
            "url": "https://article_1",
            "image_url": "https://ik.imagekit.io/xxx1",
            "data": null,
            "status": 1,
            "order": 4,
            "created_at": "2019-05-01 13:58:37",
            "updated_at": "2019-07-24 15:25:23",
            "category_label": "Article"
        },
        {
            "id": 990122,
            "category": 2,
            "name": "Article 2 Title",
            "base_url": "base_url",
            "url": "https://article_2",
            "image_url": "https://ik.imagekit.io/xxx2",
            "data": null,
            "status": 1,
            "order": 4,
            "created_at": "2019-05-01 13:58:37",
            "updated_at": "2019-07-24 15:25:23",
            "category_label": "Article"
        },
        {
            "id": 990123,
            "category": 1,
            "name": "Article 3 Title",
            "base_url": "base_url",
            "url": "https://article_3",
            "image_url": "https://ik.imagekit.io/xxx3",
            "data": null,
            "status": 1,
            "order": 4,
            "created_at": "2019-05-01 13:58:37",
            "updated_at": "2019-07-24 15:25:23",
            "category_label": "Article"
        },
        {
            "id": 990124,
            "category": 1,
            "name": "Article 4 Title",
            "base_url": "base_url",
            "url": "https://article_4",
            "image_url": "https://ik.imagekit.io/xxx4",
            "data": null,
            "status": 1,
            "order": 4,
            "created_at": "2019-05-01 13:58:37",
            "updated_at": "2019-07-24 15:25:23",
            "category_label": "Article"
        },
        {
            "id": 990125,
            "category": 1,
            "name": "Article 5 Title",
            "base_url": "base_url",
            "url": "https://article_5",
            "image_url": "https://ik.imagekit.io/xxx5",
            "data": null,
            "status": 1,
            "order": 4,
            "created_at": "2019-05-01 13:58:37",
            "updated_at": "2019-07-24 15:25:23",
            "category_label": "Article"
        },        
    ]
}
```

My Client need to improve this loading/decode speed, Any Idea ?

Comment: You are getting the problem in the paring the `JSON` response??... What i have done in my project like i have passed the **My POJO** class like  `Map userMap = jsonDecode(response);
    
        var parsedJson = json.decode(response);
    
        var status = parsedJson['status'];
    
        if (status == 1) {
          var user = new Article.fromJson(userMap);         
  
        } `

Comment: Can you share the API url here, so i can test it

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha it's internal API. However, it's so fast (i have test it). the bottleneck begin at `model = await compute(articleFromJson, json.encode(data[i]));`

Comment: It might be because you are spawning a new isolate  for each of the data item.Either you can do the conversion without using an isolate or reuse the same isolate. Also remember, whatever the parameter you give to the isolate will be copied, this can also result in a bottleneck

Answer (score 2):

You did not use the [compute()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html) function where you should be please refer to [Parse JSON in the background](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing) for the correct way of parsing JSON in a `compute()` isolate function

Comment: Can you explain your answer please? It looks to me no different than your link. If he did not place the compute call in the right spot, where should he have placed it instad?

Comment: json.encode(data[i]) DOES NOT run inside the isolate.